# Filtering WP_Query result by category

Tags: wp-query

Using WP_Query, I need to gather a selection of posts that are **both** Category1 and Category2.  I want this selection to include Category1 and all of its subcategories (Category3 and Category4), as long as they are also labeled Category2, **even if** they aren't labeled Category1.

```
Categories:

Name          ID     Parent
Category1     1
Category2     2
Category3     3      1
Category4     4      1

Posts:

ID     Categories
1      1,2
2      2,3
3      2,4
```

Now, if I were to use WP_Query to find posts in just Category1 it seems to find all three posts including Post2 and Post3 since Category3 and Category4 are subcategories of Category1 even though the posts aren't Category1.

```
new WP_Query(
        array(
            'cat' => 1
        )
```

However, if I use 'category__and' to find posts that are both Category1 and Category2

```
new WP_Query(
        array(
            'category__and' => array(1, 2)
        )
```

it only finds Post1 that has both Category1 and Category2, but it won't find Post2 that is Category2 and Category3 or Post3, even though Category3 and Category4 are subcategories of Category1.

Is there a way I can take the result of this:

```
new WP_Query(
        array(
            'cat' => 1
        )
```

Which finds posts that are Category1 AND subcategories of Category1, even if they aren't also Category1...

And then filters it to only include those posts that also are Category2?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I mistyped 'cat' as 'cat_id' in the above question, but 'cat' is what I'm actually using in my working code.  Question code has been corrected.

Comment: added some additional clarification

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. If you haven't done so, please see [ask] and also visit our [tour] page. It is important to make sure to provide correct details/code for someone to help you. This also avoids that your question gets closed due to syntax errors. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category parameters of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) does not have this type of logic. `category__and` and `category__in` does not return posts in child categories of the set categories.

I would suggest that you make use of the [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) parameters in `WP_Query`, which have the logic you are looking for. The `relation` parameter has two possible values, `AND` and `OR`

> **relation (string)** - The logical relationship between each inner taxonomy array when there is more than one. Possible values are 'AND', 'OR'. Do not use with a single inner taxonomy array.

Also, by default, child terms are included in a `tax_query`, and that is what you need.

> **include_children (boolean)** - Whether or not to include children for hierarchical taxonomies. Defaults to true.

You can do something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => 1,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => 2,
            'include_children' => false,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What this code does, it looks for posts that are in category 1 **and** in its child categories, also, it checks whether these posts from category 1 and its child categories are **also** in category 2. The list of posts returned will be posts that are in category 1 or any of its child categories **and** which is also in category 2.

I have excluded the child categories from category 2, but you can remove this if needed.

Comment: Awesome - that worked.  I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have high enough reputation yet.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Glad this worked out for you. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 3):

What describe is the way it should work:

- `cat_id` it is not a valid argument, so you get posts from all categories. Use `cat` to set one category ID or an array of categories ID. For example:

Get posts from category 1:

```
new WP_Query(
    array(
        'cat' => 1
    )
```

Get posts from category 1 and from category 2 (not in both necessarily)

```
new WP_Query(
    array(
        'cat' => array( 1, 2 )
    )
```

- `category__and` finds posts that belongs to all specified categories. For example:

Get posts that are in both categories, 1 and 2:

```
new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category__and' => array( 1, 2 )
    )
```

More details in [WP Query, category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped 'cat' as 'cat_id' in the above question, but 'cat' is what I'm actually using in my working code.  So this doesn't answer my question yet.  I want to get to find all posts that are in Category2 AND (Category1 OR SubCategories of Category1).  Your 'category__and' code does not find the subcategories