# Custom Wordpress Archive and query dont filter by categories

Tags: wp-query, custom-post-type-archives

I have a problem. I am using Hello Elementor child theme where I made new archive template. Now I added a category to the menu through categories menu item. The problem is that posts are not filtering correctly according to the categories.
The code is following:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying archive pages.
 *
 * @package HelloElementor
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
?>

<?php
$custom_query_args = (array(
   'post_type' => 'kampaania'
));

$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

?>
<main id="content" class="site-main">

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'hello_elementor_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <header class="page-header">
            <?php
         
            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            the_archive_description( '<p class="archive-description">', '</p>' );
            ?>
        </header>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="page-content">
        <?php
        while ($custom_query->have_posts() ) {
            $custom_query->the_post();

            $post_link = get_permalink();
            ?>
            <article class="post">
                <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $post_link ), get_the_post_thumbnail( $post, 'large' ) );
                } ?>
            
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
               <?php 
                $field = get_field_object('kampaania_periood'); 
                $field2 = get_field_object('kampaania_kauplused');
                ?>
                <div class="bpost-title">
                    <?php
                    printf( '<h2 class="%s"><a href="%s">%s</a></h2>', 'entry-title', esc_url( $post_link ), wp_kses_post( get_the_title() ) );
                    ?>
                </div>
         
               <p class="kamp-period">
                    <span class="kamp-period-head"><?php echo $field['label']; ?></span> <?php echo $field['value']; ?>
               </p>

               <p class="post-excerpt">
                  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
               </p>
         
               <p class="kamp-kaup"> 
                    <span class="kamp-period-head"><?php echo $field2['label']; ?></span> <?php echo $field2['value']; ?>
               </p>

               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-closer">Osale kampaanias</a>
            </div>
                
            </article>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
        ?>
        <nav class="pagination">
            <?php /* Translators: HTML arrow */ ?>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( sprintf( __( '%s Vanemad kampaaniad', 'hello-elementor-child' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span>' ) ); ?></div>
            <?php /* Translators: HTML arrow */ ?>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( sprintf( __( 'Uuemad kampaaniad %s', 'hello-elementor-child' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>


</main>
```

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Hello - It looks like you need to add the category id to the $custom_query_args array. I think this post might help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161330/filtering-wp-query-result-by-category